# Проблема с TCP сервером

Tags: сокет, c++

Пытаюсь попробовать написать простой http сервер. Для начала пытаюсь просто создать TCP сервер. Вроде бы порт биндится, но при попытке соединиться с сервером  вылетает ошибка.
[image]

```
#include "web_server.h";
#define HOST "127.0.0.1"

SOCKET Start_Server(short port)
{
    WSADATA             wsaData;
    SOCKET              Winsock;
    struct sockaddr_in  Winsock_In;
    struct hostent      *Ip;
    char                hn[1024];

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    Winsock=WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, (unsigned int)NULL, (unsigned int)NULL);
    if(Winsock == INVALID_SOCKET){
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    Ip = gethostbyname(HOST);
    Winsock_In.sin_port = htons(port);
    Winsock_In.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Winsock_In.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);//inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*((in_addr*)Ip->h_addr_list[0])));
    if(bind(Winsock, (SOCKADDR*)&Winsock_In, sizeof(Winsock_In)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
  return Winsock;
}

void GetHtmlList(FILE* f)
{
    fprintf(f, "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>ggg</TITLE></HEAD>\r\n");
}

void Main_WebServer()
{
    SOCKET              Winsock;
    char              Buf[255];
    Winsock = Start_Server(5656);
    listen(Winsock, 5);
    strcat(Buf, "TEST!!!");
     while (1)
    {
        int s;
        FILE *f;

        s = accept(Winsock, (sockaddr *)HOST, (int *)HOST);
        //send(s, Buf, (int)strlen(Buf), 0);
        if (s < 0) break;

        f = fdopen(s, "r+");
        GetHtmlList(f);
        fclose(f);
    }

  //close(Winsock);
}
```

Помогите разобраться )

Comment: Для начала набросайте printf-ов, определите в какой строке валиться. И лучше сделайте пока консольным приложением (проще отлаживать).

Подозрительно выглядит strcat(Buf, "TEST!!!"); М.б. лучше strcpy() ?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку )
Нужно так

```
struct sockaddr_in client; 
int clientsize = sizeof(client); 
s = accept(Winsock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientsize);
```

Comment: Теперь не могу понять, как это вывести в браузере. Обязательно отсылать все заголовки?

Comment: да, отсылайте заголовки <br>
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Comment: У меня просто страница висит, пытается загрузиться, но так и незагружается. 
Т.е. получается, нужно с начало принять заголовки от браузера, а потом отправить браузеру?

Comment: Советую отслеживать общение с браузеров каким-нибудь снифером. Например, http://www.wireshark.org/ 
Посмотрите, как браузер общается с работающим сервером и как с вашим.